# Slick: why would I save "Unit" to my database?

Tags: scala, slick

I'm new to Scala and Slick and was surprised by something in the Slick documentation:

> The following primitive types are supported out of the box for
>   JDBC-based databases in JdbcProfile
>
> - ...
> - Unit
> - ...

I don't get why this list contains `Unit`. From my understanding, Unit is similar to Java's `void`, something I neither can save to nor receive from my database. What is the intention behind it?

edit: you can find it [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/schemas.html).

Comment: It’s not very similar to Java’s `void`. The only similarity is that it’s used to signal that a function has only side-effects, but that’s syntactical and not semantical. The main difference between `void` and `Unit` is that there are no values of type `void`, while there is one value of type `Unit`.

Comment: @rightfold  How does your comment address the intention of the OP which I understand to be "why would Slick attempt to save a Unit data type to the DB?"   I am interested to know as well: does Slick save a Null to the DB in that case - or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to look at Slick is running Scala code on your database as the execution engine. We are working on allowing more Scala code over time. An expression that contains a unit, e.g. in a tuple is a valid Scala expression and thus should be runnable by Slick unless there is a good reason why not. So we support unit.

Comment: It would be great to see an example